# Firebase database speed up simple read

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was doing some profiling in my firebase database and I found one single anomaly

```
Read Speed
┌───────────────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Path                          │ Count │ Average     │ Permission Denied │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ /safeList                     │ 4     │ 3,092.50 ms │ 0                 │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼───────────────────┤
```

It means every request to that structure took over 3 seconds. It's not the worst problem in the world but still strange.

`safelist` is a list of strings ordered by length manually and then imported into firebase. The list contains about 8000 strings of length 5 to 25.

These requests were made by me and each of them requested only the first 5000 samples from the set.

My question is:

- Is there any way to improve the read performance?
- If I simply request the whole set instead of the first 5000 would it be faster?
- Any suggestions for a bigger sets of primitives?

==========UPDATE============

Some people are asking about data and code.

the only code where i call this query is:
`firebase.child("safeList").limitToFirst(5000).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { //do stuff`

i didn't put because is pretty dumb
and as said in the description:
**Safelist is a List of String with about 8000 items ordered manually by length**

the database rules related to it:

```
"safeList":{
         ".read":"root.child('premiums').child(auth.uid).exists()",
           ".write":false,
             ".indexOn" : ".value"
      },
```

It takes average 3000ms when the second slowest query takes only 60ms

Comment: read data into limits

go set by set

or make some service to read data in background and save it into database

Comment: It's impossible to say it things can be faster without seeing the exact data and code. See if you can reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin, so that we can have a look (the performance is likely to be quite similar between Android and JavaScript).

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to get the data from the database and please responde with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the exact data is kind impossible to share, and the code is pretty dumb as you can see in my update

Comment: @AlexMamo, i believe it is because google takes longer to reduce the set from 8k to 5k

Comment: It's still pretty vague. How are they ordered manually by length as Firebase internally orders by key. Are these key: value pairs with the key being created with push() and the value being a string (as opposed to another key: value pair). The rules include indexing by value but the query doesn't contain *orderByValue*. Did you try the same tests on a different network to see if you have lag?

Comment: @Jay your comments looks like from someone not familiar with firebase, not everything must be a key-value pair, firebase acepts lists like this. The network has no influence in this measurement since it is got from firebase infrastructure so is not accounting for any network or client delays

Comment: Typically NoSQL databases are key: value stores and in the case of Firebase Database, everything is a key: value pair. See [ref1](http://basho.com/resources/nosql-databases/) [ref2](https://database.guide/what-is-a-key-value-database/). *When you add data it becomes a node in the structure with an associated key*. The list you are referring to is a key: value pair with the 'list' being the value. The question does not give us enough info to know what the structure of that value is or where teh dataset was derived from, which is why I asked. My apologies for assuming it was via a network.